# NSError is nil but goes into not nil condition

Tags: ios, swift, ad-hoc-distribution, nserror

I have code like this in my app, which works fine with development profile. But with AdHoc provisioning profile my app is crashing when i try to print error. According to logs there should not be any error and it should be nil. but i have no idea why it is satisfying the if condition and if it is satisfying the condition then why its crashing if i try to print error. Plus this code is working fine with development profile. This issue is only with AdHoc profile. -

```
func initializedWithCredentials( credentials: GTICredentials!, error: NSError ) {
 // Check to see if initialization was successful. With log i can see that initialization was successful only so there should not be any error
if let error = error as NSError? {
      // Handle error
      NSLog("Error : \(error)")     // App Crashes 
}else{
      // Success so do something     
}
}
```

Below is the device log -

```
Incident Identifier: 17FD2BD0-4FA5-492B-891C-2EC066EAFC41
CrashReporter Key:   0fd3245f5726c1a1a90046a6629d5ccc9ebf39dd
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             VidurOnMobile [2160]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A945905D-C112-4E96-9124-775F4590E5FB/VidurOnMobile.app/VidurOnMobile
Identifier:          com.ibm.cio.be.iphone.VidurOnMobile
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-09-22 22:25:45.149 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-09-22 22:25:01.041 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8bf0d6 0x2a89c000 + 143574
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00962960 0x886000 + 903520
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00943160 0x886000 + 774496
3   VidurOnMobile                   0x00107728 0xea000 + 120616
4   VidurOnMobile                   0x00109df8 0xea000 + 130552
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x393c9c80 0x393c8000 + 7296
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x393c9c6c 0x393c8000 + 7276
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x393d554e 0x393c8000 + 54606
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2a96c664 0x2a89c000 + 853604
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2a96ad84 0x2a89c000 + 847236
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2a8b66cc 0x2a89c000 + 108236
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2a8b64de 0x2a89c000 + 107742
12  GraphicsServices                0x3227b1a4 0x32272000 + 37284
13  UIKit                           0x2e068440 0x2dff9000 + 455744
14  VidurOnMobile                   0x000fa62e 0xea000 + 67118
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x39407aac 0x39406000 + 6828

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ba24c 0x394b9000 + 4684
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x393da4ec 0x393c8000 + 74988
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x393da21e 0x393c8000 + 74270

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ce9c0 0x394b9000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954be14 0x3954b000 + 3604
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baec 0x3954b000 + 2796

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit
Thread 3:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8aa348 0x2a89c000 + 58184
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2a9dbc2c 0x2a89c000 + 1309740
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8aa344 0x2a89c000 + 58180
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38e541a4 0x38e33000 + 135588
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x393d69b4 0x393c8000 + 59828
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x393d789e 0x393c8000 + 63646
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954bd9a 0x3954b000 + 3482
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baec 0x3954b000 + 2796

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ce9c0 0x394b9000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954be14 0x3954b000 + 3604
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baec 0x3954b000 + 2796

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFNetwork.addPersistCacheToStorageDaemon
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ba49c 0x394b9000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ba290 0x394b9000 + 4752
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x393dae1a 0x393c8000 + 77338
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x393dab46 0x393c8000 + 76614
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x39560ea6 0x39560000 + 3750
5   Foundation                      0x2b7a98fa 0x2b617000 + 1648890
6   Foundation                      0x2b7a8f6e 0x2b617000 + 1646446
7   Foundation                      0x2b62abea 0x2b617000 + 80874
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2a9aa30c 0x2a89c000 + 1106700
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8d9704 0x2a89c000 + 251652
10  CFNetwork                       0x2a462e98 0x2a3d4000 + 585368
11  CFNetwork                       0x2a43179c 0x2a3d4000 + 382876
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x393c9c80 0x393c8000 + 7296
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x393d44ce 0x393c8000 + 50382
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x393d3d9c 0x393c8000 + 48540
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x393d648e 0x393c8000 + 58510
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x393d789e 0x393c8000 + 63646
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954bd9a 0x3954b000 + 3482
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baec 0x3954b000 + 2796

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ba49c 0x394b9000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ba290 0x394b9000 + 4752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2a96c5ce 0x2a89c000 + 853454
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2a96ab94 0x2a89c000 + 846740
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8b66cc 0x2a89c000 + 108236
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8b64de 0x2a89c000 + 107742
6   WebCore                         0x36723d2c 0x366a2000 + 531756
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dddc 0x3954b000 + 11740
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dd4e 0x3954b000 + 11598
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baf8 0x3954b000 + 2808

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394cdb2c 0x394b9000 + 84780
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954d354 0x3954b000 + 9044
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954e224 0x3954b000 + 12836
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x38600fa4 0x385fb000 + 24484
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2bbd3206 0x2bbbe000 + 86534
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2bbcf6bc 0x2bbbe000 + 71356
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dddc 0x3954b000 + 11740
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dd4e 0x3954b000 + 11598
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baf8 0x3954b000 + 2808

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394cdb2c 0x394b9000 + 84780
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954d354 0x3954b000 + 9044
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954e224 0x3954b000 + 12836
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x38600fa4 0x385fb000 + 24484
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2bd98140 0x2bbbe000 + 1941824
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2bd981a4 0x2bbbe000 + 1941924
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2bbcf6bc 0x2bbbe000 + 71356
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dddc 0x3954b000 + 11740
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dd4e 0x3954b000 + 11598
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baf8 0x3954b000 + 2808

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ba49c 0x394b9000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ba290 0x394b9000 + 4752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2a96c5ce 0x2a89c000 + 853454
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2a96ab94 0x2a89c000 + 846740
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8b66cc 0x2a89c000 + 108236
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2a8b64de 0x2a89c000 + 107742
6   CFNetwork                       0x2a451422 0x2a3d4000 + 513058
7   Foundation                      0x2b6e7186 0x2b617000 + 852358
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dddc 0x3954b000 + 11740
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dd4e 0x3954b000 + 11598
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baf8 0x3954b000 + 2808

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ce9c0 0x394b9000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954be14 0x3954b000 + 3604
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baec 0x3954b000 + 2796

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ce9c0 0x394b9000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954be14 0x3954b000 + 3604
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baec 0x3954b000 + 2796

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x394ce080 0x394b9000 + 86144
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2a970d80 0x2a89c000 + 871808
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dddc 0x3954b000 + 11740
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954dd4e 0x3954b000 + 11598
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3954baf8 0x3954b000 + 2808

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000004
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00d416c0      r7: 0x00884c44
    r8: 0x1768cf00    r9: 0x175b8774     r10: 0x00884cf0     r11: 0x3bded0e0
    ip: 0x0068c2e0    sp: 0x00884c18      lr: 0x00962964      pc: 0x2a8bf0d6
  cpsr: 0x60000030
```

Comment: From definition of the function, the error cannot be nil. error: NSError

Comment: error is optional so it can be nil or some error. In this case there should not be any error and should go into else condition, but its going into if condition and also crashing if try to print error. Plus this issue is only with AdHoc profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error cannot ever be nil if the definition of function is error: NSError. If the error could be nil, it should be defined as error: NSError?. Otherwise there is no point of trying unwrap non-optional value. It should look like this:

```
func initializedWithCredentials(credentials: GTICredentials!, error: NSError? ) {

    if let error = error {
      // Handle error
       NSLog("Error : \(error)")
    } else {
      // Success so do something     
    }
}
```

Even better, you should avoid nesting if conditions

```
func initializedWithCredentials(credentials: GTICredentials!, error: NSError? ) {

    if let error = error {
       // Handle error
       NSLog("Error : \(error)")
       return
    } 

    // Success so do something     
}
```